# How should I refactor this conditional helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to achieve is a label that shows how many comments there are on a page. Currently the code works to show what I need, but I believe this is not the right way and could use some refactoring.

Also, should I move the `h1` tag out into the view instead or is `content_tag` acceptable?

What I need is basically to put "Be the first to comment" if there are no comments and pluralize the label if there are comments.

Thanks for your help on this.

```
   def number_of_comments
     @review.comments.count
   end

   def render_comments_count
      if number_of_comments == 0
        content_tag(:h1, "Be the first to comment")
      elsif number_of_comments  == 1
        content_tag(:h1, "1 comment")
      else
        content_tag(:h1, number_of_comments) + content_tag(:h1, "comments")
      end
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pluralize and extract the h1 to the view:

```
def number_of_comments
  @review.comments.count
end

def render_comments_count
  if number_of_comments.zero?
    'Be the first to comment'
  else
    "#{number_of_comments} #{'comment'.pluralize(number_of_comments)}"
  end
end
```

Then, in the view:

```
<h1><%= render_comments_count %></h1>
```